# jQuery animation on nested divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate, slidedown

I'm trying to create a nav of links that correspond to different divs in the page, and when you click on the link, it hides all the other divs and slideDown the respective div. I am almost there, but as you can see, it only seems to work on anything that isn't a nested div. (So if I include just text inside that section or p tags or anything else, it will show, but not the children divs.) My code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/DScMX/16/

Furthermore, I want to be able to display the latest year (in my example) when the page is loaded, and then when clicking on each year, as mentioned, it hides what's on the page and displays the correct section.

```
<div id="years_links">
    <a href="#" id="2013">2013</a> | 
    <a href="#" id="2012">2012</a> | 
    <a href="#" id="2011">2011</a>
</div>
<div id="yearscontent">
    <div id="2013">
        <pclass='item'>some 2013 stuff</p>
    </div>

    <div id="2012">
        <div class='item'>some 2012 stuff</div>
    </div>

    <div id="2011">
        <div class='item'>some 2011 stuff</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var yearscontent = $('#yearscontent');
    $('#yearscontent div').hide();
    $('#years_links a').click(function() {
        var year = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#yearscontent div').slideUp(300);
        $('#yearscontent #'+year).slideDown(300);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('#yearscontent div')` selects all divs below `#yearscontent`. If you use `$('#yearscontent > div')`, it will select only the direct descendant of `#yearscontent`.

Also, element id's need to be unique, so you'll need to rework your html/script a little bit. I would use classes instead.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N5euG/

**Update** to answer your question in the comments

Consider this html:

```
<div id="topDiv">
    <div id="div1">
        <div id="div2">
            <div id="div3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="div4"></div>
```

`#topDiv div` will select `#div1`, `#div2`, and `#div3`. Any `div`s within `#topdiv`

`#topDiv > div` will select only `#div1`. Just the direct descendant of `#topDiv`.

Comment: His script isn't failing because of the duplicate id's, but there are still duplicate id's, which should be fixed.

Comment: `<a href="#" id="2013">` and `<div id="2013">` etc.

Comment: Ah, thank you! But, what's the difference between all divs below an id, and the direct descendants? Does "all divs below" mean past the end of #yearscontent, to the bottom of the page?

Comment: @kburla - *All divs below* include all descendants - including children and children-of-children. *Direct descendants* include only children, but not children-of-children.

Comment: @kburla Updated answer with an example to answer your question.

Comment: But why would it fail if it was told to open all nested children? Isn't that what I'm asking it to do? Anyway, I modified the links a bit to use unique IDs :) http://jsfiddle.net/N5euG/7/ I'm not sure where I would use classes in this case though..

Comment: `$('#yearscontent div').slideUp(300);` was hiding the nested divs, and `$('#yearscontent #'+year).slideDown(300);` was only showing the outer div, so the nested div remained hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I added in some CSS so and an "active" class so that your slide up and down isn't jittery.

```
#yearscontent div:nth-child(1n+2) {
    display:none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N5euG/8/

Comment: Then all you have to do is change the CSS  
`#yearscontent > div:nth-child(1n+2) {
        display:none;
    }`